# HTML5 video ontimeupdate event doesn't work in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video

I'm trying the HTML5 video tag as in [this example](http://my.opera.com/core/blog/2010/03/03/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio-2), but not everything is working.

I want to use the `ontimeupdate` event to print current video time:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<video src="test.ogv" width='640' height='480' controls='controls'>
</video>
<div id=time>time</div>
<script>
var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
var time = document.getElementById('time');
video.ontimeupdate = function(e) {
  time.innerHTML="Current time: " + video.currentTime;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This works in Opera and Firefox, but not in Google Chrome.
So, why does this code not working in Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me, maybe chrome's bug/fault your code doesn't work

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<video src="test.mp4" width='640' height='480' controls='controls' ontimeupdate="timeupdate();">
</video>
<div id=time>time</div>
<script>
    var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    var time = document.getElementById('time');
    function timeupdate() {
        time.innerHTML = 'Current time: ' + video.currentTime;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```